# how do i create and allow a user to select multiple list items from a multi-select "widget" in python and or bash?

Tags: python, bash, multi-select

i'm fairly new to python but not to programming.  i'm working on a program that needs to turn a list of items into a multi-select widget of some kind so that a user can choose multiple items (preferably with a mouse vs solely using the keyboard) from the list which are then passed to and processed by the rest of the program.  i've got everything i need in my program except for converting the list to multiselect functionality.

i've searched all over the web high and low and i can't find much of anything here.   everything i find is related to working with the lists themselves (slicing, etc) versus *visually* creating an interface element which allows a human being to do the selections not program code.  does anybody have any suggestions or pointers?

i'd probably prefer a non-curses solution but if curses is easier to implement i don't mind.  i started looking into trying to do this graphically but there were so many different GUI tool kits for python and their project pages didn't look very "maintained" so i'm not sure which one might be best to use (ie which one has good documentation, examples, will be around in the next 5 years and generally supports most major platforms while providing the multi-select functionality i want).

if it's possible, i'd prefer to only spawn the gui for the multi-select functionality and then return back to the text-based python program versus writing the whole program as a complete gui application.  but i'm flexible as well.

if there is some other non-python toolkit, application or filter that will provide the multi-select functionality by allowing my program to fork or pipe it while passing a list and then receiving control back with the new user defined multi-select list, that's fine too.  i don't care. i just need the functionality.

i'm currently on a mac and am well-versed in linux / bash scripting etc if that matters.

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Consider looking at [xdialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/), [Zenity](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Zenity), or any of the various other tools designed to integrate simple GUI functionality with shell scripts.  These all typically require X11, though, so they probably won't help on a Mac.  Python's core [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) module is pretty easy to use, especially if your needs are modest.

Comment: thanks for the input.  i am unfortunately on a mac though :)  i may have to go tkinter.  does anybody else have thoughts on any of the other python gui toolkits?